# Doorkeeper /oauth/token - blank response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, doorkeeper

I have a front-end in AngularJS and back-end in RoR with Devise + Doorkeeper + RocketPants. 
For now I have properly working CORS, I can succesfully get json responses from my API (if I turn off doorkeeper protection). But now I'm trying to implement user password credentials flow:

On doorkeeper:

```
  resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    request.params[:user] = {:email => request.params[:username], :password => request.params[:password]}
    request.env["devise.allow_params_authentication"] = true
    request.env["warden"].authenticate!(:scope => :user)
  end
```

On angularjs (src: [nils-blum](http://nils-blum-oeste.net/cors-api-with-oauth2-authentication-using-rails-and-angularjs/)):

```
var payload = "username="+username+"&password="+password+"&" +
        "client_id="+client_id+"&client_secret="+client_secret+
        "&grant_type=password"

$http({method: 'POST',
    url: scope.booksh_server + '/oauth/token',
    data:   payload,
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }
).success(function (data) {
            tokenHandler.set(data.access_token);
            scope.$broadcast('event:authenticated');
});
```

Note: Nils's approach uses payload as object with params, not a string. In my case it gives me POST with payload, not with FORM params, and thus not working.

When I enter wrong user/password, rails log says:

```
    Started POST "/oauth/token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-22 15:21:08 +0400
  Doorkeeper::Application Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "oauth_applications".* FROM "oauth_applications" WHERE "oauth_applications"."uid" = '981d6d654f5e709b2ca3437401c993a6d09cc91cc3fb16b8e2b3191e6421029c' AND "oauth_applications"."secret" = 'f92c4ec969525352bd03ec1eb810a9952cd0814d37ce5b2b02e8a928b2561e10' ORDER BY "oauth_applications"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'undefined' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Chrome dev tools show this request as cancelled. Firebug shows empty response with 302 Found status. When I perform same POST from chrome [REST App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon), UPD: server does the same, and I get 302 Found and then it's redirected to sign_in page of devise.

Moreover, if I enter correct user/password, firefox shows empty response with 200 OK, REST receives proper json with access token, and chrome shows cancelled response and throws CORS error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0:3000/oauth/token. Origin http://0.0.0.0:9000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Server log:

```
Started POST "/oauth/token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-22 15:33:22 +0400
  Doorkeeper::Application Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "oauth_applications".* FROM "oauth_applications" WHERE "oauth_applications"."uid" = '981d6d654f5e709b2ca3437401c993a6d09cc91cc3fb16b8e2b3191e6421029c' AND "oauth_applications"."secret" = 'f92c4ec969525352bd03ec1eb810a9952cd0814d37ce5b2b02e8a928b2561e10' ORDER BY "oauth_applications"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = '123@gmail.com' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "remember_token" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["last_sign_in_at", Fri, 22 Nov 2013 11:32:49 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", Fri, 22 Nov 2013 11:33:23 UTC +00:00], ["sign_in_count", 24], ["remember_token", "N5sRI6vE7B6vRNUlih3G2Q"], ["updated_at", Fri, 22 Nov 2013 11:33:23 UTC +00:00]]
   (17.5ms)  COMMIT
   (1.6ms)  BEGIN
  Doorkeeper::AccessToken Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "oauth_access_tokens" WHERE "oauth_access_tokens"."token" = '72dd81fd85b638fb14f9d081193b1eda0e58f85d6820718ab635fe195c36a689' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "oauth_access_tokens" ("application_id", "created_at", "expires_in", "resource_owner_id", "scopes", "token") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["application_id", 1], ["created_at", Fri, 22 Nov 2013 11:33:23 UTC +00:00], ["expires_in", 7200], ["resource_owner_id", 1], ["scopes", ""], ["token", "72dd81fd85b638fb14f9d081193b1eda0e58f85d6820718ab635fe195c36a689"]]
   (28.1ms)  COMMIT
```

How can I make this work? I need POST /oauth/token to process authentication and respond with access_token in case email/password were correct. 
Any help is appreciated, I'm tired of being stuck at this )

Comment: Great question! Unfortunately, there are so many gems involved that finding an answer will need a huge investment of time.

Comment: *Nils's approach uses payload as object with params, not a string. In my case it gives me POST with payload, not with FORM params, and thus not working.* - I don't understand this point. The username and password are present in the payload data of the POST request which means you can extract them on the server. Why do you say that your case is different?

Comment: *And it returns proper json object with access_token. As I can understand, that's because of cookie '_doorkeeper-provider_session', supplied with request, but I can't find, where to destroy it.* - For a single test, you can simply destroy it in your browser's cookie manager and see if it still works.

Comment: @Chandranshu I don't know why, but if I POST with params encoded in string, doorkeeper processes it, and if I use object - no (object is sent as json, maybe that's the problem. But I can't understand, why Nils's article uses this approach then)
OK, I found how to destroy cookie - it should be found not on page of rest client, but on page with my api. Destroyed it, and now REST client request is processed as correct one from chrome or firefox, and it again returns proper json. Seems like server responds the same way in all cases. I'll update the post with case without cookies.

Comment: That is a relief to hear that the server responds in the same fashion in both the cases otherwise we'd be pulling our ears and hair trying to make it consistent. I'm still doubtful about what is it that gets sent to your application from the browser. Is there any way I can access your API/site? I need to pick my wife from her office and head home. Let me know if it's possible in comments and we can take this discussion forward in a chatroom.

Comment: @Chandranshu well, I can host it on my VPS in 10 minutes, or you can just connect to me via skype or google hangouts - it'll be easier.

Comment: @Chandranshu I have to go now, gonna return by 18:30 (GMT). Add me in skype: morodeer .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41709/discussion-between-chandranshu-and-morodeer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yay! Finally I made it work. Still dunno why in tutorials all over the web it's much easier.

So, where the problem comes from: in my `ApplicationController` (root one, not the one that handles API) I had following for CORS:

```
  before_filter :set_headers

  def set_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://0.0.0.0:9000'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
  end
```

Digging into the problem I've found that this function is not called when I call /oauth/token but is called when I go to any other route outside of API which is processed with `ApplicationController`

Doorkeeper has its own controllers independent from your app controller. Docs describes changing of their behavior well ([link](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-routes)), so here is what helped me:

routes.rb:

```
use_doorkeeper do
    controllers tokens: 'custom_tokens'
end
```

custom_tokens_controller.rb:

```
class CustomTokensController < Doorkeeper::TokensController

  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  before_filter :set_headers

  def set_headers
    puts 'headers set'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://0.0.0.0:9000'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
  end
end
```

Important thing is to include `Callbacks` into controller, as Doorkeeper controllers are inherited from `Metal`, so without inclusion rails can't find `before_filter`.

It looks good now: It authenticates my user/password pair, and returns access_token (I hope, it works :D ). If something is wrong, now there should come redirect. This is the problem which I know solution to (custom warden failure), so everything is OK now. Huh! It was long... If anyone knows why internet-based recipes didn't help, please post your thoughts =)

Comment: Storing the `client_id` and `client_secret` client-side seems very insecure - do you use this method in production? I'm facing the same situation :-/

Comment: Hello, Chris. Unfortunately I haven't moved any further neither with that project nor with Rails, so no, I don't have this in production.